# query was empty in search php

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to make this search with a select option to select which site, or all the sites.
When i click on all sites it works. When i click on "4shared" it works. But when i click "putlocker" i get this. Query was empty.

I really dont know what i did wrong

```
<?php 
include"inc/connect.php"; 
include"inc/functions.php";
error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s'] != ""){
    $s = $_GET['s'];
    $w = $_GET['w'];

    if($w == 'all'){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM result WHERE (`name` LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (`keywords` LIKE '%".$s."%')";
    }else if($w == 'Sockshare'){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM result WHERE website='Sockshare' AND (`name` LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (`keywords` LIKE '%".$s."%')";
    }else if($w == 'Putlocker'){
        $sql == "SELECT * FROM result WHERE website='Putlocker' AND (`name` LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (`keywords` LIKE '%".$s."%')";
    }else if($w == '4shared'){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM result WHERE website='4shared' AND (`name` LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (`keywords` LIKE '%".$s."%')";
    }else if($w == 'Rapidshare'){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM result WHERE website='Rapidshare' AND (`name` LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (`keywords` LIKE '%".$s."%')";
    }

    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($count > 1){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $name = $row["name"];
            $details = $row["details"];
            $url = $row["url"];

            $results .= '
            <div id="stitle">' .$name. '</div>
            <div id="details">' .$details. '</div>
            <div id="url"><a target="_blank" href="' .$url. '">' .$url. '</a></div>';
        }
        } else {
            $results = 'Nothing found!';
        }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Findrfile.com - Putlocker Search | Sockshare search | Mediafire Search</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orienta' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<?php include"header.php"; ?>
<div id="spacer"></div>
<?php include"litsearch.php"; ?>
<div id="nuresults"><span class="blue"><?php echo $count; ?> Results found</span></div>
<div id="spacerx"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="spacerx"></div>
<div id="content">
<?php echo $results; ?>
<div class="clear"></div>

</div>
<div id="spacerx"></div>
<div id="spacer"></div>
</div>
<?php include"footer.php"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you check the values? maybe there are white spaces around them...

Comment: You also have an [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) problem. (And you should show an error message if `$w` doesn't match any of those accepted values.)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

You have `$sql == "SELECT * FROM result WHERE website='Putlocker' AND (name LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (keyword LIKE '%".$s."%')";` notice the `==`, this is a comparison operator so it won't set a value to `$sql`
I think that may be your issue.

Comment: You're welcome.  If that does fix your issue, I'd appreciate you accepting the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
```

to

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
```

Because you use associative array.

```
        $name = $row["name"];
        $details = $row["details"];
        $url = $row["url"];
```

If you want to use

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
```

like:

```
    $name = $row[0];
    $details = $row[1];
    $url = $row[2];
```

Am I wrong?

ALSO:

you check if $_GET["s"] is set but you do not check $_GET["w"]

Comment: thanks, i tryed that but i still get that error when i choose putlocker